# sandbox - How to get paypal payment details if failed to return back

Tags: paypal, payment, paypal-standard

I am using Paypal Sandbox for at my site to process payments.

I am saving payment stuffs after the user returned successfully to the store using an URL defined for payment successful/canceled.

But suppose the user loses connection due to any technical issue (e.g. server down or failed internet connection), then how I will get the payment details,  especially in cases of the paid orders?